# How to add a note to a workflow using Activiti

Tags: java, xml, workflow, activiti, bpmn

I am trying to visualize an existing workflow using Java and Activiti.

I am using an own workflow engine in the background but it is really unclear because it just presents the workflow data in table form. This is why I want to transform the data from the tables into a standard BPMN 2.0 form. Therefore the package org.activiti.bpmn.model is used. The different tasks are created by the UserTask class, the SequenceFlows are generated as expected and the layout is designed by the automatic bpmn layout function of Activiti. My problem now are the different pre-conditions and the effects a user task has. In some cases there are so many that it would be too much text to just add them as name of a sequence flow. My idea was just to add a node to the user task where I can add a String that includes these things but I did not find a fitting object that solves this problem. I have tried the Message object in combination with the MessageFlow object but it did not work as I hoped it would.

After creating the workflow it is saved as XML file and to check how the transformed workflow looked it is uploaded at bpmn.io (at the moment including a Message object that is not presented if the XML file is uploaded at bpmn.io):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
  <message id="message123" name="This is a test message" itemRef="ut5"></message>
  <process id="process" name="New Prod" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="startEvent" name="New Product"></startEvent>
    <exclusiveGateway id="exclusiveGateway1"></exclusiveGateway>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow-672ba4b9-2f30-41b4-b638-bb05cde15cde" sourceRef="startEvent" targetRef="exclusiveGateway1"></sequenceFlow>
    <userTask id="ut1" name="Workbox Musterprodukte"></userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow-20c9fdf5-52f4-4c8c-9d30-9522b8cac16b" name="Check: mobile Category set" sourceRef="exclusiveGateway1" targetRef="ut1"></sequenceFlow>
    <exclusiveGateway id="exclusiveGateway2"></exclusiveGateway>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow-0651ad02-735a-4311-bf3c-55bb6146e764" sourceRef="ut1" targetRef="exclusiveGateway2"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow-039e61e4-6404-4fc8-b074-606ec2e0032a" name="Check: mobile Category NOT set" sourceRef="exclusiveGateway1" targetRef="exclusiveGateway2"></sequenceFlow>
    <userTask id="ut2" name="Step1"></userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow-833b5285-e302-4ab3-a0fc-b1442ec4909f" sourceRef="exclusiveGateway2" targetRef="ut2"></sequenceFlow>
    <parallelGateway id="pg1"></parallelGateway>
    <userTask id="ut3" name="Step2A"></userTask>
    <userTask id="ut4" name="Step2B"></userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow-b5f991a9-4d2c-4537-8ab2-7d5a6449cdf1" sourceRef="ut2" targetRef="pg1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow-7c12d9ea-c96f-4715-a8a5-39654053225a" name="Check: Main Image available" sourceRef="pg1" targetRef="ut3"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow-19439ed1-2af5-43c4-8abf-df013fe24cdc" name="toom_Freigabe_CM = y" sourceRef="pg1" targetRef="ut4"></sequenceFlow>
    <parallelGateway id="pg2"></parallelGateway>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow-faf33a66-a6db-4636-8ddf-d46484dbaa1e" sourceRef="ut3" targetRef="pg2"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow-6180eea1-14e6-47c8-9e68-d6c3aed0b322" sourceRef="ut4" targetRef="pg2"></sequenceFlow>
    <userTask id="ut5" name="Step3"></userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow-efb2cef7-0b4a-410b-b076-19f0cf0a97ce" sourceRef="pg2" targetRef="ut5"></sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="end" name="Step4"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow-7129e658-6004-4004-907b-f1ea6d5602a3" sourceRef="ut5" targetRef="end"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_process">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="process" id="BPMNPlane_process">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="ut2" id="BPMNShape_ut2">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="60.0" width="100.0" x="410.0" y="73.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="ut1" id="BPMNShape_ut1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="60.0" width="100.0" x="170.0" y="130.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="exclusiveGateway2" id="BPMNShape_exclusiveGateway2">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="40.0" width="40.0" x="320.0" y="78.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="exclusiveGateway1" id="BPMNShape_exclusiveGateway1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="40.0" width="40.0" x="80.0" y="76.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="ut4" id="BPMNShape_ut4">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="60.0" width="100.0" x="650.0" y="160.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="ut3" id="BPMNShape_ut3">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="60.0" width="100.0" x="650.0" y="0.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="startEvent" id="BPMNShape_startEvent">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="30.0" width="30.0" x="0.0" y="81.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="ut5" id="BPMNShape_ut5">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="60.0" width="100.0" x="890.0" y="80.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="pg2" id="BPMNShape_pg2">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="40.0" width="40.0" x="800.0" y="90.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="end" id="BPMNShape_end">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="30.0" width="30.0" x="1040.0" y="95.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="pg1" id="BPMNShape_pg1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="40.0" width="40.0" x="560.0" y="88.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow-7129e658-6004-4004-907b-f1ea6d5602a3" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow-7129e658-6004-4004-907b-f1ea6d5602a3">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="990.0" y="110.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1040.0" y="110.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow-efb2cef7-0b4a-410b-b076-19f0cf0a97ce" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow-efb2cef7-0b4a-410b-b076-19f0cf0a97ce">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="840.0" y="110.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="890.0" y="110.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow-672ba4b9-2f30-41b4-b638-bb05cde15cde" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow-672ba4b9-2f30-41b4-b638-bb05cde15cde">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="30.0" y="96.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="80.0" y="96.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow-039e61e4-6404-4fc8-b074-606ec2e0032a" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow-039e61e4-6404-4fc8-b074-606ec2e0032a">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="120.0" y="88.5"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="132.0" y="88.5"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="132.0" y="98.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="320.0" y="98.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow-833b5285-e302-4ab3-a0fc-b1442ec4909f" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow-833b5285-e302-4ab3-a0fc-b1442ec4909f">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="360.0" y="98.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="372.0" y="98.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="372.0" y="103.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="410.0" y="103.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow-6180eea1-14e6-47c8-9e68-d6c3aed0b322" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow-6180eea1-14e6-47c8-9e68-d6c3aed0b322">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="750.0" y="190.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="762.0" y="190.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="762.0" y="110.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="800.0" y="110.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow-0651ad02-735a-4311-bf3c-55bb6146e764" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow-0651ad02-735a-4311-bf3c-55bb6146e764">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="270.0" y="160.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="282.0" y="160.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="282.0" y="98.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="320.0" y="98.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow-b5f991a9-4d2c-4537-8ab2-7d5a6449cdf1" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow-b5f991a9-4d2c-4537-8ab2-7d5a6449cdf1">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="510.0" y="103.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="522.0" y="103.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="522.0" y="108.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="560.0" y="108.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow-faf33a66-a6db-4636-8ddf-d46484dbaa1e" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow-faf33a66-a6db-4636-8ddf-d46484dbaa1e">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="750.0" y="30.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="762.0" y="30.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="762.0" y="110.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="800.0" y="110.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow-7c12d9ea-c96f-4715-a8a5-39654053225a" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow-7c12d9ea-c96f-4715-a8a5-39654053225a">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="600.0" y="100.5"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="612.0" y="100.5"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="612.0" y="30.000000000000007"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="650.0" y="30.000000000000007"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow-20c9fdf5-52f4-4c8c-9d30-9522b8cac16b" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow-20c9fdf5-52f4-4c8c-9d30-9522b8cac16b">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="120.0" y="103.5"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="132.0" y="103.5"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="132.0" y="160.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="170.0" y="160.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow-19439ed1-2af5-43c4-8abf-df013fe24cdc" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow-19439ed1-2af5-43c4-8abf-df013fe24cdc">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="600.0" y="115.5"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="612.0" y="115.5"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="612.0" y="190.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="650.0" y="190.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use the documentation field in either the activity or sequence flow.
In the XML it looks like this:

```
<sequenceFlow id="flow4" sourceRef="usertask1" targetRef="exclusivegateway1">
  <documentation>This is some element documentation.</documentation>
</sequenceFlow>
```

Then in the BPMN editor it will be displayed as documentation.
Really interesting project you have going on.

Greg

Comment: I have tried it that way and the process part of the XML includes the description but the text I have set as Documentation is not shown in the diagram. 
I think the best object to use would be the TextAnnotation. But there I have the same problem. I attach the TextAnnotation to the process instance via addAtrifact(). But the bottom part of the XML which provides the information on the layout does not contain any information on that object so it is also not displayed in the diagram.

Comment: So, now I know that I need an Association which links the UserTask with the TextAnnotation but I get a NPE when BpmnAutoLayout is executed. The failing method is generateAssociationDiagramInterchangeElements(). Somehow the method receives a null value when executing getState(Edge).